# How can Keras training be stopped manually while also returning the best weights?

Tags: keras

I am using Keras 2.2.4 and normally I use the Keras `EarlyStopping` callback to halt training *while ensuring that the best weights observed during that training are returned*. So, I have something like the following:

```
stop_early = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor              = 'val_loss',
    min_delta            = 0.0001,
    patience             = 300,
    verbose              = 1,
    mode                 = 'auto',
    baseline             = None,
    restore_best_weights = True
)
```

What would be some way I could get Keras to halt the training *and to return the best weights*, as though the criteria given to `EarlyStopping` had been met? I have in mind the idea that there could be some callback a bit like `EarlyStopping` that checks routinely for the existence of some file, e.g. `safeword`, at the working directory. How might this or similar be done?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and probably the most robust solution would be to just use the `ModelCheckpoint` callback with `save_best_only=True` and implement the halting separately depending on... well, whatever you need, really.

For a program running in CLI, you don't really need anything special, just throw a KeyboardInterrupt with Ctrl+C. Anything more fanciful, well, that depends on what you have in mind; one way or another you'll need to have something listening to I/O events asynchronously or after each epoch - but that part of the question is probably better suited for StackOverflow.